# What should I do with my crippled Bitcoin Core? How can it be this unstable still after 10+ years?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development

Recently, I've had serious issues with my Bitcoin Core. I've installed old versions and reinstalled the new version and done everything to debug it, but it's just crippled.

It either gets stuck forever with a "Done loading" text (never starting), or it does get into the "sync mode" but shows "12 days behind" even though it was 8 **hours** from being fully synced yesterday, etc.

Basically, I can no longer trust anything it displays, and I'm utterly unable to make any payments.

Luckily for me, I don't currently have a need to make Bitcoin transactions, but that's only because I have nothing going on in my life and am desperately trying to find a way to start making money (Bitcoin). What if I had actually been doing business? Then I'd be entirely helpless now. Or if my VPN expires now, I'd have to make a new yearly Bitcoin payment, but Bitcoin Core doesn't let me.

It seems to suddenly have decided to be forever stuck in sync mode. With everything that I've tested, and the discussions I've read with others having similar issues, I frankly no longer have the energy to specify in detail everything I've tried. I'm just wondering how this situation can arise at all.

I consider Bitcoin Core to be critical software; just one step away from "life-supporting systems". It must be rock-solid and just work. Of course, my `wallet.dat` is well backed up on external, encrypted drives inside a fireproof safe, so I don't think I'll lose any coins or even that Bitcoin Core will corrupt the "live" wallet.dat file. I just mean that it's in an unusable state and this is not the first time this (or similar things) has happened.

Right now, it doesn't even let me bring up the GUI at all. And a minute ago, it let me, but was 100% blank. As in, nothing drawn inside the window.

If there are still intelligent people out there who believe in Bitcoin and want to get rid of the suffocating tentacles of the "traditional banks", I wish they would step up and at least fix this basic software to be *far* more stable and reliable.

I truly don't know what to do other than "wait and pray" for it to sync itself (again) and then maybe it will allow me to actually use it.

I'm a "poweruser". Imagine what the average person would think and behave in a situation like this.

Comment: As the other user commented, almost all performance and instability complaints with Bitcoin Core come down to underlying hardware concerns. Using VPN services will have a detrimental effect on your sync speed, as they are usually extremely bandwidth constrained.

Answer (score 1):

> **What should I do with my crippled Bitcoin Core?**

I would buy a new computer, and download and install a fresh copy of Bitcoin-core onto it, then replace the wallet.dat file using your backup copy and let Bitcoin core fully sync.

> **How can it be this unstable still after 10+ years?**

I'd suspect something on your existing PC is causing issues. I'd remove the wallet from that PC and just use the PC for other things. I'd consider wiping the PC clean and doing a fresh install of the operating system and applications.